# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $gH$ is in $Hg$ for some $g$. Can we get that $gH=Hg$?

Tags: group-theory

I know it is true if *H* is finite,but how about *H* is infinite?Any ideas are welcome
.Thanks.